# How to implement Referral/Affiliate program in ICO presale?

Tags: ico, presale

We are developing a ICO presale site and want to integrate referral program into our project.
After checking some presale sites, we found they are using youpromote.care as below.

```
https://bs_c7b6c438.youpromote.care?aff=185601
https://bs_603e1f64.youpromote.care?aff=185616
```

They are redirecting to their own sites with clickId as below.

```
https://deelance.com/en?clickId=fx_b24259_99957736fa9b81b04ca9bad237e54eea_1
https://www.launchpad.xyz/en?clickId=fx_b28864_628d16ce11f59a47ee2532c5af864dd_1
```

We want to implement the similar thing, but couldn't know where can we start.
Would you please give me a clue?
Thanks